# Parsing XML document by JAVA DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, try-catch

I need to get some data from XML document and I am using XML parser. I was following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm) procedure and there is part of code:

```
File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
```

After this there is more traversing in XML document and getting data. Since methods newDocumentBuilder() and parse() throws exceptions, they need to be placed inside try-catch block. **My question is**: Should I put all my code inside try-catch block (also traversing and getting informations from XML - like in example on tutorialspoint.com), or can I put inside try-catch only these two methods :

```
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
```

What is the right solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the exception that are thrown from other call or declare it on your method. The approach I always follow is to identify if an exception is thrown by programmer vs jvm and try to write programmer thrown exception inside try-catch block, this way I always have a benefit of adding custom code in catch block, it could be anything like adding some logging, etc to help debug your program when such exceptions are caught.